# Java ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay starts new thread to execute the task without waiting for 1st task to complete

Tags: java, scheduling

I am writing a piece of code where I need to periodically schedule a Runnable. I am using ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay with initial delay as 0 and delay as 2 minutes. There is only task in this SchedulerService. I am expecting that 2nd execution of the task will start 2 minutes after the completion of 1st execution of the task. To validate this, I started my app in debug mode and placed a breakpoint at the beginning of the Runnable Task. 1st execution halts at the breakpoint and thread executing the task goes in suspended state. To my utter surprise, after 2 minutes of the start of 1st execution of the task, SchedulerService starts new thread to execute 2nd execution of the task. I was expecting that unless 1st execution completes, ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay will not start 2nd execution. Please help me understand this behavior as this contradicts the Javadoc explanation of this method.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post your code so that people can look at it as suggest changes required.

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads are controllable. Single threaded executor can be initiated.
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Comment: Can't use this, as the same ScheduledService will eventually be shared by multiple components. For my testing, I have disabled other components right now.

Comment: The scheduler service's default behavior is running the tasks at the given interval. It will not wait untill a task is completed to start the next. Making the executor single threaded is one option to handle such behavior. If it is not possible you required you have to handle it at the task level. Try using completable futures to handle this behavior.